# php facebook api to post on facebook wall publish_actions

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

We have developed a shopping website and we used facebook login and when customer purchases we have posted the product in their wall previously. To perform this operation I have created an application in developer.facebook.com using xxx@test.com.

If I use xxx@test.com and login into my site and purchase a product It is posting to facebook wall but If I use different account getting exception as

```
user not authorized application
```

And I started googling and finally I submitted publish_actions permission for review

[image]

Whether this is the only way to post in fb wall? Why it is posting with xxx@test.com alone?

Here is the code I have used

```
public function postFbWall($customer_name) {

    if(!isset($this->fbconnect)) {
            require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'vendor/facebook-sdk/facebook.php');
            $this->fbconnect = new Facebook(array(
                'appId'  => $this->config->get('fbconnect_apikey'),
                'secret' => $this->config->get('fbconnect_apisecret'),
                "cookie"=>true,
            ));
            $_SERVER_CLEANED = $_SERVER;
            $_SERVER = $this->clean_decode($_SERVER);
    }
    $fbuser = $this->fbconnect->getUser();
    if($fbuser){
        try {
            $fbuser_profile = $this->fbconnect->api("/$fbuser");
            $access_token = $this->fbconnect->getAccessToken();
            $message = "First three users who registers through this links will get 5% of the product price as reward points";
            $attributes = array(
                'name' => $customer_name,
                'caption' => HTTP_SERVER,
                'access_token' => $access_token,
                'message' => 'message goes here',
                'link' => 'link',
                'description' => 'description goes here',
                            );
            $ch = curl_init();
            $purl = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$fbuser."/feed";
            $mattr = "";
            foreach($attributes as $key=>$value):
                $mattr .= $key."=".$value."&";
            endforeach;
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$purl);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($attributes));
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$mattr);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE ,true);
            $res = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $resultobj = json_decode($res);
            if(isset($resultobj->id)) { $res =true;} else {$res=false;}
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $fbuser = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pre-filling message is now allowed by Facebook Platform Policy. So you will never be approved as long as you do that

Comment: @WizKid Sorry what you are trying to say I am unable to understant...

Comment: Read https://developers.facebook.com/policy and specifically 2.3: "Ensure that all content in the user message parameter is entered by the user. Don’t pre-fill. This includes posts, messages, comments, and captions". There is also a video explaining what pre-filling is.

But the short version is that the user have to type in the message them self manually.

Comment: Above message is static just for example, message will be dynamically created as I mentioned posting product in facebook wall. This too not possible?

Comment: Dynamically created is also against policy. The user them self have to type in the message.